# React - disable eslint error about path like import labelsMap from "./translations.json?labels";

Tags: reactjs, eslint

In my Typescript component I have the following import:

`import labelsMap from "./translations.json?labels";`

How to prevent eslint from throwing an error like `Cannot find module './translations.json?labels' or its corresponding type declarations.`

my eslint.js:

```
const baseRules = {
  camelcase: "off",
  "eslint-comments/no-unused-disable": "error",
  "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", { devDependencies: true }],
  "import/order": "off",
  "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
  // 'import/extensions': [
  //     'error',
  //     {
  //         ts: 'never',
  //         tsx: 'never',
  //         json: 'never',
  //     },
  // ],
  "import/extensions": "off",
  "jest/prefer-to-have-length": "warn",
  "jest-dom/prefer-enabled-disabled": "warn",
  "jest-dom/prefer-in-document": "warn",
  "promise/always-return": "warn",
  "promise/catch-or-return": "warn",
  "react/no-did-update-set-state": "warn",
  "promise/no-nesting": "warn",
  "promise/no-return-wrap": "warn",
  "react/forbid-prop-types": "off",
  "promise/param-names": "off",
  "no-shadow": "off",
  "react/jsx-no-bind": [
    "error",
    {
      ignoreRefs: true,
      allowArrowFunctions: true,
      allowFunctions: true,
      allowBind: false,
      ignoreDOMComponents: true,
    },
  ],
  "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": "off",
  "react/no-array-index-key": "warn",
  "react/require-default-props": "off",
  "react/sort-comp": "off",
  "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn",
  "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "warn", // change react-hooks rules to error after fixing warnings
  "no-console": "error",
  "no-alert": "error",
  "no-use-before-define": "off",
  "testing-library/no-node-access": "warn",
  "jsx-a11y/*": "off",
  "class-methods-use-this": "off",
  "react/no-unknown-property": [
    "error",
    { ignore: ["css", "ctx", "download"] },
  ],
  "import/no-unresolved": "off",
};

module.exports = {
  extends: [
    "airbnb",
    "airbnb/hooks",
    "plugin:promise/recommended",
    "plugin:eslint-comments/recommended",
    "plugin:jest/recommended",
    "plugin:jest/style",
    "plugin:testing-library/react",
    "plugin:jest-dom/recommended",
    "prettier",
    "plugin:storybook/recommended",
    "plugin:react/jsx-runtime",
  ],
  parser: "@babel/eslint-parser",
  parserOptions: {
    sourceType: "module",
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
  },
  settings: {
    "import/resolver": "webpack",
    "import/core-modules": [
      "@tra-ui/components/modal",
      "@tra-ui/components/v2",
      "@tra-ui/components/react-components-forms",
    ],
  },
  env: {
    browser: true,
    jest: true,
    node: true,
  },
  rules: {
    ...baseRules,
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
      files: [
        "*.ts",
        "*.tsx",
        "*.test.js",
        "*.test.jsx",
        "*.test.ts",
        "*.test.tsx",
      ],
      parserOptions: {
        project: ["tsconfig.eslint.json"],
        sourceType: "module",
        ecmaFeatures: {
          jsx: true,
        },
      },
      extends: [
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
        "airbnb",
        "airbnb-typescript",
        "airbnb/hooks",
        "plugin:promise/recommended",
        "plugin:eslint-comments/recommended",
        "plugin:jest/recommended",
        "plugin:jest/style",
        "plugin:testing-library/react",
        "plugin:jest-dom/recommended",
        "prettier",
        "plugin:import/typescript",
      ],
      rules: {
        ...baseRules,
        "@typescript-eslint/ban-types": [
          "off",
          {
            types: {
              object: "off",
            },
          },
        ],
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
        // '@typescript-eslint/quotes': ['error', 'single'],
        "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": "off",
        "react/destructuring-assignment": "off",
        "import/no-named-as-default": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment": "off",
        // 'import/extensions': ['error', 'never', { json: 'off' }],
        "jsx-a11y/*": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/lines-between-class-members": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface": "off",
        "react/prefer-stateless-function": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": "off",
        "react/prop-types": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-shadow": "off",
        "import/no-unresolved": "off",
        "no-useless-escape": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
        "import/extensions": "off",
        "react/jsx-uses-react": "off",
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
      },
    },
    // {
    //     files: ['*.test.js', '*.test.jsx', '*.test.ts', '*.test.tsx'],
    //     rules: {
    //         'no-param-reassign': 'off',
    //     },
    // },
  ],
};
```

My tsconfig.eslint.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "outFile": "index.d.ts",
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "@appTypes/*": ["src/types/*"],
      "hooks/*": ["src/common/hooks/*"],
      "common/*": ["src/common/*"],
      "types/*": ["src/types/*"],
      "components/*": ["src/common/components/*"],
      "features/*": ["src/features/*"],
      "module/*": ["src/module/*"],
      "service/*": ["src/service/*"],
      "test/*": ["src/test/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["dom", "es2015", "es2015.promise", "es2017"]
  },
  "include": ["./src/*", "./src/**/*", "./node_modules/@tra.eu/space-types"]
}
```

my package.json:

```
  "name": "@tra-ui/dsa-components",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Components repository",
  "main": "babel-plugin-import.js",
  "types": "index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "addMissingTypes": "cp -r ./node_modules/@tra.eu/space-types ./@spaceTypes",
    "build": "webpack --bail && tsc",
    "build:watch": "webpack --watch",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist",
    "components:link": "yalc add @tra-ui/components && yalc link @tra-ui/components && npm i -f",
    "components:unlink": "yalc remove @tra-ui/components && npm i -f",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .jsx --ext .js src",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --ext .tsx,.ts,.js,.jsx --fix ./src",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build",
    "storybook": "npm run addMissingTypes && storybook dev -p 6006",
    "storybook:build": "npm run addMissingTypes && storybook build -c .storybook -o dist_storybook",
    "test": "jest --coverage --no-cache --passWithNoTests",
    "test:components": "concurrently \"npm run storybook\" -k -s first",
    "test:update": "jest --updateSnapshot --coverage --passWithNoTests",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch --coverage --passWithNoTests",
    "test:watch-no-coverage": "jest --watch --no-coverage --passWithNoTests"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "extends @tra.eu/browserslist-config"
  ],
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm"
  },
  "author": "Orr",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "@tra-ui/components": "^21.255.2",
    "@tra.eu/webpack-tralations-plugin": "^2.4.2",
    "camelize": "^1.0.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-is": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.13.14",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.3",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.21.5",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.0.18",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "^7.1.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^7.0.0",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^8.19.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@tra.eu/browserslist-config": "^1.1.1",
    "@tra.eu/space-types": "^3.4.2",
    "@tra.eu/webpack-yalc-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/eslint": "^7.29.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.168",
    "@types/prop-types": "^15.5.6",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.15",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.14.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "^4.14.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.14.0",
    "auto-styles-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.3",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.3.3",
    "babel-plugin-traform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.15",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "^5.2.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "directory-named-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.18.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^14.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.13.2",
    "eslint-plugin-eslint-comments": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.3.6",
    "eslint-plugin-jest-dom": "^3.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-modules-newline": "0.0.6",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sort-destructure-keys": "^1.3.5",
    "eslint-plugin-sort-imports-es6-autofix": "^0.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sort-keys-fix": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.12",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^4.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-typescript-sort-keys": "^1.8.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "generate-json-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "incstr": "^1.2.3",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-css-modules": "^2.1.0",
    "jest-webpack-resolver": "^0.3.0",
    "loader-utils": "^2.0.0",
    "metro-memory-fs": "^0.59.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.2",
    "postcss": "^8.2.4",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.1.1",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.62.1",
    "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
    "smart-glob": "^1.0.2",
    "spritesheet-templates": "^10.5.2",
    "spritesmith": "^3.4.0",
    "storybook": "^7.0.18",
    "string-hash": "^1.1.3",
    "styled-components": "5.3.3",
    "stylelint": "^13.9.0",
    "stylelint-config-css-modules": "^2.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^22.0.0",
    "stylelint-order": "^4.1.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^3.18.0",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.6",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "webpack": "^5.79.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1",
    "webpack-virtual-modules": "^0.5.0",
    "yalc": "^1.0.0-pre.53"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```